# XML document from class path resource

Tags: spring-jdbc

I am getting this error. I am following an online example. It was running fine till I added Spring.xml to get jdbc login values from xml file.

My XML file is under src folder

Main code:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");, 
JdbcImpl daoImpl = ctx.getBean("jdbcImpl", JdbcImpl.class);, 
IdpTpgInputFile idpInputFile = daoImpl.getInputFile(1);, 
System.out.println(idpInputFile.getFileName());
```

Error:

```
Apr 16, 2013 5:24:36 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@b61d36b:
    startup date [Tue Apr 16 17:24:36 PDT 2013];
    root of context hierarchy
Apr 16, 2013 5:24:36 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring.xml]
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: 
    Line 18 in XML document from class path resource [spring.xml] is invalid;
    nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException:
        Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "name".
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396),
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334),
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302),
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143),
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178),
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149),
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
        ,at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:126),
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:92),
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130),
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467),
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397),
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139),
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83),
        at com.amar.jdbc.JdbcMain.main(JdbcMain.java:21)
```

Comment: paste the content of spring.xml out please.

Comment: Please get used to post all useful info so the people can help you easier (like spring.xml, or anything else in other questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that an open quote for an element type "name" is missing at line 18 in the spring.xml. Please check. Good luck:)

Comment: Now I get the following Error: 
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource com.amar.jdbc.util.JdbcImpl.dataSource; nested exception is

Comment: this is another question, please take my answer at first. and then I'll help you to solve this problem :)

Comment: please paste out the error message where starts with "Caused by..." at the bottom.

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource com.amar.jdbc.util.JdbcImpl.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.class] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [resources/spring.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Comment: the content after "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: " is key porint.paste more.

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.class, at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514), at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)... 13 more

Comment: Is spring-jdbc.jar existing in your project library?

Answer (score 2):

looks like you missed below statements in your ApplicationContext.xml file. check once.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
```